# Oracle SQL trying to Hash 25 columns in one column

Tags: sql, oracle, hash

So when I was trying to hash 25 columns using ORA_HASH function I was getting error: too many parameter.
Is there any way we can hash all 25 columns and quickly because we have around 60M rows and no Update date :(

```
select  ORA_HASH
  (id,name,c....,...) form table name
```

Comment: Hashing is a function of a single variable. How do you propose to get a single value out of 25 columns? If they are all VARCHAR2 perhaps you can concatenate them all together (although there will be some undesired effects: 'a' || 'bc' = 'ab' || 'c' so the hash will be the same even though the tuples are not). But ORA_HASH can't be used with CLOB, so if the result of concatenation is too long, you won't be able to use ORA_HASH on the result. So... why are trying to do this? Are you sure this is the best way?

Comment: What is your end goal here?

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation with some special string as delimited e.g. here chr(10) assuming this charter doesn't appear in you data

```
 col1||chr(10)||col1||....
```

Be carefull with numeric and data columns.

Either convert them explicitely in character columns, e.g.

```
...||to_char(col_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')||...
```

or temorary override the session setting to have a constant values

```
 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.']';
 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

The problem with NLS setting is, when they change and you perform a default conversion to character string - you get a different hash code.

Note also, that  ORA_HASH can lead to duplicates, consider e.g.  `MD5` hash code to recognise change in the table data.

Final note Oracle has a (not well known) function [DBMS_SQLHASH.GETHASH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/appendixb.htm#CHDGHCAE) whitch may or may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: DBMS_SQLHASH is not mentioned in the documentation for 12.2, 18c and 19c. Looks like it fell through the cracks. Too bad, would have been interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Surely your ultimate goal is not to get a hash? What is the hash for? It may very well not be the right way to achieve your goal.

Second, `ORA_HASH` is a weak, 32-bit hash that will produce a hash collision about every 25,000 rows! I wrote a whole blog post about this, see:

https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/compare-and-sync-tables-dbms_comparison/

Third, starting with version 12c there is a `STANDARD_HASH` function that seems to perform quite well and that goes up to 512 bits! (not bytes as I said before editing this answer...)

Finally, the right way to hash several things together is "hash chaining", not concatenating the values. `ORA_HASH` appears to support hash chaining (or something of similar effect) using the third parameter:

```
ora_hash(column1, 4294967295, ora_hash(column2))
```

With `STANDARD_HASH`, I would first use it on each column individually, then use `UTL_RAW.CONCAT` to concatenate the results, then either use `STANDARD_HASH` on the concatenated result or just use the concatenated value as if it were a big hash.